# How do I get to the frontpage in the new mobile topbar

Tags: support, mobile-web, top-bar, homepage

I see that the new topbar has been rolled out on the mobile version of the site (for meta at least)

> [image: New Mobile Topbar]

However, it is not very clear how you can return to the front page.  In the prior version, you would get the front page by clicking the site name in the topbar.  However, with the new topbar, all this does is expand the topbar to show my user info and the search icon (the same behavior as you used to get by clicking the down arrow in the top right corner).

> [image: New Expanded Topbar]

For most sites, I know I can still get the active questions by changing the "order by" dropdown in the questions page, but how will this work for sites where the front page is not necessarily the same as the active page (specifically Stack Overflow which has the "interesting" tab only on the front page).  And since the front page has different ordering options (like "bugs", "req", "hot", etc), you can't get everything you need on the questions page as you can on the front page.

Answer (score 3):

You can get to the front page from the SE logo drop-down. It's not one-click away anymore.

[image: SE-logo - Explore our sites - Stack Overflow - Meta Stack Overflow]

Comment: That's true, but IMO it a rather long path just to get to the frontpage of the site I'm already on.  The front page is supposed to be the front page of the site, so it shouldn't require a series of actions to get there.

Comment: I agree. The link to the front page should be available through one click. It's not really obvious that you can use that path either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can also use the "Questions" link under the top bar. It will remember which version of the "front" page you were on. If you were viewing the "active" questions, it will take you there. Likewise if you were viewing the "newest".

[image: questions-link]

Comment: Not really.... you can already change that by clicking "order by" (which I mentioned).  And technically the frontpage and the active tab are different in some respects.  For meta they have the same content, but for SO, the front page is not the same as the active tab, so when this top bar rolls out there it is not immediately clear how you would access it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 FWIW you can only click "order by" if you are already viewing questions. If you are viewing your profile that action does something else.

Comment: I know (as I mentioned "order by")... but the active tab of the question's page is not the same as the front page.  I have tried to clarify that in my question a bit more.